# ASP.NET / Javascript page formatting issues when using javascript ot update status

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a page (twitter bootstrap theme) that is using javascript to update the user as the page loads as to where in the process the script is.  The first line of HTML therefore is:

```
<div id='mydiv' >_</div><script>mydiv.innerText = '';</script><!DOCTYPE html>
```

My code then updates the mydiv element with where it is and once complete then runs the page_load function and displays all the information.

The problem is that this is causing formatting issues in Internet Explorer.  IE goes into quirks mode, I am assuming because the

```
<!doctype html>
```

is not at the top of the page.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` should always be at the beginning of the document. Why do you have a div outside of your document's body, anyway?  I'm assuming that the script you posted is a sort of stub of what you're really doing, otherwise it doesn't make sense to set text in an element, just to unset it via javascript immediately after that element loads. Can you clarify your intentions there?

Answer (score 1):

Having that `div` like that, whether that's causing your specific problem or not (my guess is yes), needs to be fixed. You can't have invalid HTML like that and expect it to behave nicely.

Definitely move that div and script into the appropriate place - I'm guessing the top of the `body`, and I'd bet that solves your problem.

Comment: Technically that fixes the problem but it also removes the ability to give status updates as to what is going on with the page.  I suppose I have a lot more research to do.

Comment: You should never have to write to the top of the document. If you can describe how that div appears, maybe we can help point you in the right direction for putting it in the body dynamically.